# Displaying only Pixel Position and hide Pixel Values in Matplotlib Navigation Toolbar Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

I am trying to plot data on tkinter canvas using matplotlib "imshow()" function. When I am running the code the data is getting plotted onto the canvas and in the navigation toolbar pixel coordinates (x and y coordinates) are getting displayed along with pixel values (in bracket). Issue is I want to display only the pixel coordinates and hide pixel values which is getting displayed in the navigation toolbar.

The code which I am using is:

```
import tkinter
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import (
    FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2Tk)
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import tkinter
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import (
    FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2Tk)
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

root = tkinter.Tk()

fig = Figure(figsize=(5, 4), dpi=100)
fig.subplots_adjust(bottom=0, right=1, top=1, left=0, wspace=0, hspace=0)

ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

class Formatter(object):
    def __init__(self, im):
        self.im = im
    def __call__(self, x, y):       
        return 'x={:.01f}, y={:.01f}'.format(x, y)

data = np.random.random((10,10))

im = ax.imshow(data, interpolation='none')
ax.format_coord = Formatter(im)
plt.show()

canvas1 = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=root)
canvas1.draw()

toolbar = NavigationToolbar2Tk(canvas1,root)
toolbar.update()
toolbar.pack(side=tkinter.TOP, fill=tkinter.X, padx=8)

canvas1.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tkinter.TOP, fill=tkinter.BOTH, expand=1, padx=10, pady=5)

canvas1._tkcanvas.pack(side=tkinter.TOP, fill=tkinter.BOTH, expand=1, padx=10, pady=5)

root.mainloop()
```

Kindly suggest how to hide pixel values getting displayed in the navigation toolbar (inside brackets) and display only pixel coordinates (x & y coordinates).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value in the navigation toolbar is created by the images' `format_cursor_data` method. You can replace that method to return an empty string.

```
im = ax.imshow(data, interpolation='none')
im.format_cursor_data = lambda e: ""
```

Answer (score 1):

One way is to override the method `mouse_move`:

```
class Navigator(NavigationToolbar2Tk):
    def mouse_move(self, event):
        self._set_cursor(event)
        if event.inaxes and event.inaxes.get_navigate():
            try:
                s = event.inaxes.format_coord(event.xdata, event.ydata)
                self.set_message(s)
            except (ValueError, OverflowError):
                pass
        else:
            self.set_message(self.mode)

...

toolbar = Navigator(canvas1,root)

...
```